# How to silence inbound Email notifications,messages , etc?

Tags: ios, email, sms

I want to silence incoming email and text messages when my app is in foreground and background

Comment: In foreground and background? Isnt that asking too much for the patience of the user?

Answer (score 1):

That's controlled by the OS. You can't block it.